# Creating a Linux Docker for parity on a Windows 10 machine

Tags: parity, windows, docker

I'm trying to run parity on Docker.
My workstation is Windows 10, but the Docker is intended for a Linux machine.
Right now I'm having trouble running the Docker with `--base-path` option, as I keep getting the following error:

`Client service error: Client(Database("IO error: directory: Invalid argument"))`

This is the docker command I'm running:

`docker run -v /d/parity/docker:/root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/ -p 8180:8180 -p 8545:8545 -p 8546:8546 -p 30303:30303 -p 30303:30303/udp parity/parity:v1.7.9 --unsafe-expose --base-path /root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/`

Does anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also running docker on windows 10 and had very similar problem when using parity in docker with the help of this project:

https://github.com/paritytech/parity-deploy

This creates docker compose file and configuration files for you. After starting the container I got the same error. I suspect it has to do something with the differences in the file systems between the windows and linux.

Solved it by creating the volume and mounting /parity/data (in your case /root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/) to that volume.

To create volume:

```
docker volume create myvolume
```

Then in compose file I've added volume:

```
volumes:
  myvolume:
    external: true
```

and in compose file in the parity container configuration replaced volume mapping

```
- ./data/is_authority:/parity/data
```

with

```
- myvolume:/parity/data
```

So with your docker run command I'd try replacing

```
-v /d/parity/docker:/root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/
```

with

```
-v myvolume:/root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/
```

Comment: Can you describe a bit more, I ran into the same problem and have no idea how to use the compose file. I guess you mean config.toml, but it has to be reachable first.. I just started with docker as my parity for windows won't work anymore

Comment: Sorry, that was not quite clear, I admit, I will try to clarify that in my answer. Docker compose file is yml file that you use to configure your docker containers instad of using _docker run_ command, but you can do the same thing also with run command. I've created the yml with [this project](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-deploy), but run into this problem (at least I suspect it's the same one).